# Interpolating climate data over DEM in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, interpolation

I tried to interpolate climate data using IDW  by inserting DEM raster as a mask, but I got the Map of precipitation levels  without taking into account elevation data.

How can I get map of precipitation in according of DEM?

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.1.

Comment: How do you expect the elevation data to impact the precipitation data?

Comment: How the precipitation vary on different elevations

Comment: Can you give more details about what you tried? Screenshots of input parameters and your output would be great, with details of how the output differs from what you want. I am confused about how you are trying to use the DEM. I would expect comparing precipitation to elevation to be two steps - first, interpolate climate data to make a precipitation surface, and then second compare precipitation and elevation.

Comment: @ycartwhelen How can i compare precipitation and elevation data?

Comment: That's a question of statistics (spatial and non-spatial). The most basic non-spatial way would be to think of your data as a bunch of pairs (one per pixel location if you've got your rasters aligned and sharing the same pixel locations). For example, (10m in DEM, 15mm precip). Then you could do regression comparing elevation against precipitation.

Comment: You need 3d interpolation, look at scipy package, it comes with arcgis. Coding required.